# High-light menu item

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a one-page website with a menu like this:

```
<ul id="menu-menu" class="nav">
    <li id="1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="1" class="sub"><a href="#">Item 2-1</a></li>
            <li id="1" class="sub"><a href="#">Item 2-2</a></li>
            <li id="1" class="sub"><a href="#">Item 2-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="1"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li id="1"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The menu is high-lighted by JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[  */   
    var J = jQuery.noConflict();
    J(document).ready(function(){
        
        J('.nav li:first').addClass('current');
        
        J('ul.nav').each(function() {
            J(this).find('li#1').each(function(i) {
                J(this).click(function(){
                    J(this).addClass('current');
                    J(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
                });
            });
        });
    }); 
    /* ]]> */  
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click on Item 3 and than on Item 2-2, Item 3 stays high-lighted., and when I than click on Item 1, Item 2-2 stays high-lighted.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you really have all `<li>` elements with the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();
J(function(){
    J('ul.nav li:first').addClass('current');

    J('ul.nav li').click(function (e) {
        J('ul.nav li.current').removeClass('current'); 
        J(this).addClass('current');
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the event click from bubbling up
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, but when I now click on Item 2-2, all the sub Items are hilighted included Item 2... Can you solve this?

Comment: Yes. Use this CSS: `li.current > a { /* whatever highlighting you have */ }`

Comment: Wow, now we are close! When I click on Item 2-2, only the parent (Item 2) is hilighted. But thanks so far!

Comment: @Marko: Good to hear. What was the last problem you had?

Comment: When I clicked on Item 2-2, only the parent (Item 2) was hilighted.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try to replace

```
J(this).addClass('current');
J(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
```

with

```
J('ul.nav .current').removeClass('current');
J(this).addClass('current');
```

.

The problem is that the sibling selector only finds just that, the siblings, and not the other elements.